# how to get google drive api styled file contents surrounding query hits

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to find all files that contain the text "lorem" and I'm able to do so with "fullText contains 'lorem'" which lists all the files but I was interested in getting the snippets of the text that you see with the query string[s] bolded included in the response. How do I do that? Is that another API? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no direct way to obtain the snippets of text by just using the drive API. A possible workaround would be to get all the `IDs` from your `list` API call and iterate each file to get all the content and search for the snippets of text with your query string.

Comment: Also can you provide your existing code for your API request that lists all files with the query string